# Trouble getting location on device with Ionic 2 application

Tags: angular, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am having trouble using Ionic 2 Geolocation on real Android device. I have my location switched on on my Android device and I also tried reinstalling Ionic 2 and Cordova plugin for Geolocation, but I still cannot get location on my device. The code works fine when I test it on browser tho'. There is no error neither is the callback for success. I also tried testing it on different devices, but none worked properly. My code is the following:

```
loadMap(){
   this.error = "";
   let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

   let mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
     zoom: 15,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

   this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);



   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mapOptions).then((position) => {
     alert("Ready.");
   }, error => alert("Not ready."));
};
```

I tried to do simple thing at first, so to load a map (which loads with no problems) and to get a location ready. `this.geolocation` is of type `Geolocation`. I also tried to get the location using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)`, but it also didn't do anything.
I hope someone can help.
Thank you in beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was an Android version compatibility issue in my case... I tried running it on device that had Android 6.0 Marshmallow installed and everything worked fine... Later I updated Android on my own device and tried running the application. Fortunately it ran nicely also on my device after the update. Hope this helps to solve someone else's issues too. Cheers